# reactive js nested templates not handled

Tags: ractivejs

I am trying to use nested templates using reactivejs in this jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2hLzhwyd/3/

```
 <script id="templateMain" type="text/ractive">   
<div>Inputs:</div>
<div>
    {{#inputs:index}}
  <div>
  <div>Input Number {{index}}:</div>
    <template-input input={{.}} />
  </div>
  {{/inputs}}
  </div>
  <div>Rows:</div>
<div>
  {{#rows:index}}
  <div>
  <div>RowNumber {{index}}:</div>
  <template-row row={{.}} >
  </div>
  {{/rows}}
  </div>

</script>
```

But I can't make the nested template to work, only the first level template is handled.

In the jsfiddle We can see that if the "template-input" is at the first level so it is handled, and if it under another template ("template-row") it is not handled

I saw the same question here:
[ractivejs component nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681820/ractivejs-component-nesting)
but I didn't succeed make the answer to work.

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you very much!

Gadi

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `isolated:false` to the component

Eg:

`var templateInput = Ractive.extend({ isolated:false, template: '#templateInput' });`
`var templateRow = Ractive.extend({ isolated:false, template: '#templateRow' });`

Herewith a [Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2hLzhwyd/6/)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `templateRow` component does not know about the `template-input` component.

In order to do so, either define `template-input` globally:

```
Ractive.components['template-input'] = Ractive.extend(...)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2hLzhwyd/15/

Or internally:

```
var templateRow = Ractive.extend({ template: '#templateRow',
     components: {
         'template-input': templateInput
     }
 })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2hLzhwyd/13/

I strongly advise against using `isolated:false` if you are unsure what you are doing as it may lead to unwanted side effects.